# I need to get resource usage of Pods in a Kubernetes Cluster with kubernetes python client

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

i have linux command to get the resource usage of the pods in particular namespace what is the equivalent python command for it

```
$ kubectl top pod
NAME                                CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
nginx-deployment-7fd6966748-57mt5   0m           2Mi             
nginx-deployment-7fd6966748-jpbjl   0m           2Mi             
nginx-deployment-7fd6966748-snrx4   0m           2Mi
```

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/435 , see if it works.

Comment: Thanks @TarunKhosla this worked like a charm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the input the following command worked fine

```
>>> from kubernetes import client, config
>>> 
>>> config.load_kube_config()
>>> api = client.CustomObjectsApi()
>>> resource = api.list_namespaced_custom_object(group="metrics.k8s.io",version="v1beta1", namespace="default", plural="pods")
>>> for pod in resource["items"]:
...    print(pod['containers'], "\n")
...
```

Comment: what is "api" object? how to import or create?

Comment: `api` object here is [CustomObjectsApi](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md), also see examples in this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/435#issuecomment-563383704)

Comment: Thanks @Nabin and Marius Balčytis i will update my answer

Comment: @PradeepPadmanabanC, is there any way to use these kubernetes snippet inside a running pod?

Comment: @SwapnilMasurekar yes refer this https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/in_cluster_config.py

Answer (score 3):

There is no single command.

Kubernetes metrics are exposed on metrics.k8s.io. You will have to write program to query the API and get results.

For example for nodes.

This API is made available under the /apis/metrics.k8s.io/ endpoint

kubectl get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes" | jq for node metrics

Answer (score 0):

You can run kubectl commands with python as well.

```
from subprocess import call
call('kubectl describe pod pod_name_here -n default', shell=True)
```

So you can filter anything with the Python Kubernetes library and also use kubectl commands to ease your work.

Comment: this is not using kubernetes-python-client

Comment: This is just a workaround since Kubernetes does not support it, I do not see the reason for the -1. The Python ideia might help somebody in need.